# Drupal paths not taking i18n / Multilingual-ness into account?

Tags: drupal-7, internationalization

I have i18n on my Drupal website. If I am currently on the "spanish" version of the site, and I have this code:

```
drupal_get_path_alias("node/171");
```

It returns

```
about-us
```

I was expecting it to return:

```
es/about-us
```

How do I make drupal_get_path_alias aware of languages? Or must I include the prefix myself manually each time?

Answer (score 0):

the language prefix has nothing to do with the path-alias. You could for instance not use path-prefix to determin language, but a cookie. Or maybe evne a sub-domain, or a different tld.

The language-prefix simply has nothing to do with the path-alias

Comment: But I have it set up so each language start with the prefix. So why is it not taking that into account?

Comment: Because language and path alias have nothing to do with each other